# What happens to the old permissions during the new Facebook app review process?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to add publish_actions permission to my Facebook app login permissions.

For that I need to resubmit the app for a review.

I have tried to go through the docs, but it is very unclear to me what will happen to the old permissions during the review process.

Are the old permissions still valid during the process, in other words my app is still accessible?

If the new submission is approved, will the new permissions replace the old ones or are they added to them?

Comment: Yes, of course they are available during the time you submit for review, and yes of course all previously granted permissions will still be granted. (Unless you modified your app and changed the functionality you got them originally reviewed for massively to something not allowed - if they catch that, then of course there would be trouble.) Everything else would just make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. Thats what I thought, but when talking about app in production and very business critical parts, better safe than sorry.